# Localized rc file will not compile

Tags: internationalization, compilation, rc

I have a pretty standard C++ win32 application that has been internationalized. The problem is that the translated rc files will not compile. The only differences between the English rc, which does compile, and the translated rcs, which do not compile, are the LANGUAGE, code_page and the translated text. For example:

```
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
#ifdef _WIN32
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)
#endif //_WIN32
```

became

```
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_JPN)
#ifdef _WIN32
LANGUAGE LANG_JAPANESE, SUBLANG_DEFAULT
#pragma code_page(932)
#endif //_WIN32
```

and

```
IDC_TOOLMENU MENU 
BEGIN
    POPUP "&File"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "E&xit",                       IDM_EXIT
    END
    POPUP "&Help"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&About ...",                  IDM_ABOUT
    END
END
```

became

```
IDC_TOOLMENU MENU 
BEGIN
    POPUP "&ファイル"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "閉&じる",                       IDM_EXIT
    END
    POPUP "&ヘルプ"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&バージョン情報 ...",             IDM_ABOUT
    END
END
```

When I try to compile the Japanese rc I get the following error:

```
1>.\ja\Resources.rc(47) : error RC2121 : BEGIN expected in menu
1>.\ja\Resources.rc(47) : error RC2104 : undefined keyword or key name:
```

Google has not been particularly helpful in this case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem. My translated rc files were UTF-8 and rc.exe only supports ANSI or UTF-16LE.